# Problem accessing individual modules after update to joomla 3.6.4

Tags: update, joomla-3.6, module-manager

I just updated my joomla site on my dev machine to 3.6.4 and I'm having a problem with the module manager. I can access the module manager just fine, but when I try to edit a module I get sent to a white page with a drop down list of modules but not other info. [image]. I'm relatively new to joomla, so I've never experienced anything like this before. Any ideas what this is or how I can diagnose it? where would I stick php error reporting to get more information about why this is failing?

Update: I also get this problem when trying to access modules through the module assignment tab via menus...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this, clear your browser and joomla cache. The javascript handling the module manager UI was changed and conflicts with what is stored.